# Orbit space of usual action on n-cube $[0,1]^n$ by n-symmetric group $S_n$ is homeomorphic to topological n-simplex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I do see it's true for $n=2$  i.e. action of $S_2$ on $[0,1]^2$ as it's just given by identification through reflection w.r.t. the diagonal $x=y$. But, I don't have a concrete map for higher $n$ 's.

Comment: *Hint*: sort the coordinates.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that helped @user10354138. So, the orbit space is the subspace {$(x_1,...,x_n)$ | this is an increasing (not strictly) sequence} which is the n-simplex with vertices $(0,...,0),(0,0,...,0,1),(0,0,...,0,1,1),...(1,1,..,1)$.

Comment: @Mathematician-to-be Then you should answer your own question. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .